# Custom pgf shape: how to always stoke, sometimes fill?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-shape

I'm designing a collection of custom PGF shapes which will nearly always need to be stroked but only very occasionally filled. The experience I'd like the user to have is

1. With no other keys provided the shape is stroked black with no fill.
2. If a color is provided then the stroke is colored, and if `fill=color` is provided then the shape is filled.

This behavior is almost achieved by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}

\pgfdeclareshape{my circle}{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{3mm}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[my circle, draw] at (0,0) {};
        \node[my circle, draw, red] at (1,0) {};
        \node[my circle, draw, red, fill=yellow] at (2,0) {};
        \node at (4,0) {\small unboxed text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image so produced is exactly as desired; the undesirable part is that `draw` has to be provided every time `my circle` is to be drawn. As mentioned above this is undesirable because in the context of the package the shapes will virtually always need to be *at least* stroked (but not always filled).

Is there a way to modify this code so that the same picture is produced but `draw` can be omitted from the `my circle` nodes (*i.e.*, the shape is always stroked and can also be colored/filled if desired)? I've tried variations of `\pgfpathuse{stroke}` and `\pgfpathuse{fill, stroke}` in the shape declaration but can't get quite the right behavior. I would prefer to keep using shapes within nodes because that's convenient for other aspects of the package (like anchoring and placement).

Comment: Consider `my circle/.style={shape=mycircle, draw}`; this allows user to disable drawing by `node[my circle, draw=none]`.

Comment: That works perfectly and is much easier than messing with some of the PGF commands I was digging in to. If you'll make this an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you defined a Ti*k*Z style

```
\tikzset{my circle/.style={shape=mycircle, draw}}
```

that invokes the shape and also draws it by default.
So by

```
node[my circle, fill=red]{...}
```

it actually means

```
node[shape=mycircle, draw, fill=red]{...}.
```

The users can always turn the drawing off by

```
node[my circle, draw=none]
```

or by knowing the internal name of the shape.